# Describe the open balls for the Post Office metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ be the metric space consisting of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. Let $a$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}$ and consider the function $d$ given by $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} |x-a| + |a-y| &\text{if}\,\,\,\,x\neq y \\ 0 &\text{if}\,\,\,\, x=y \end{cases}$$

Let $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $b\neq a$. Describe the open ball $B_{r}^{d}(b)$ centred at $b$ of radius $r$ with respect to the distance $d$, for all possible $r>0$.

---

So far all I can think of is to consider $$\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-a|+|a-b|<r\} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-a|<r\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|a-b|<r\}$$ and then say that for $r\leq |a-b|$ we have $B_{r}^{d}(b)=\{b\}$, but I'm not sure where to go from there or if I'm approaching this right at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\vert x - a \vert + \vert a - b \vert < r \iff \vert x - a \vert < r - \vert a - b \vert$. You know the case where $r \le \vert a - b \vert$. Now think of open balls in the Euclidean metric.